# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to PROCEDURE with no input parameters Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a procedure with no input parameters

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Procedure1 (getnames OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN
  open getnames FOR 

  select * from table;

END Procedure1;
```

I am using entity framework 6 and this is the code in the edmx model

```
public virtual int PROCEDURE1()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("PROCEDURE1");
    }
```

and calling this in my controller like this

```
var list = Db.PROCEDURE1();
```

This throwing an

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to PROCEDURE error.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full procedure (there's no `create or replace procedure ...` in your example procedure).